# What to do with these tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've started looking at the first few tags that people are using, and I think that we should keep a close eye on this. Here's a few tags that I propose to "erase" or modify:

- [embedded-schema](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-schema): delete, there is already a [schema](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) tag.
- [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration): <strike>delete, too generic. To discuss whether we should have "<module>-configuration" tags</strike> **EDIT** As mentioned in Glenn's answer, we'll keep this one but it should never be used by itself. Use [cme](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme)[configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) and not [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) by itself.
- [deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment): delete, too generic. Deployment may mean a lot of different things in Tridion, and none of the things that comes to my mind means the same that the poster had in mind
- [polling](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling): delete. Only used by Transport, right?
- [long-running](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-running): delete.
- [extension-model](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension-model): too generic. Everything in Tridion can be extended, and the model will be different depending on what you are extending. If we must identify that something is an extension, then I propose to use "extensions" instead of "extension-model"
- [communicator](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communicator): I didn't even know of the communicator until about 2 months ago, as it is a (rather important) small part of the CME. I'm not sure if there's enough volume of communicator issues or questions to justify its own tag, I'd rather use [cme](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme) instead.
- [wcf](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcf): <strike>rename to core-service? Or maybe question is specific to how WCF does something rather than the Tridion Core Service?</strike> Makes sense to keep [wcf](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcf) for questions that are WCF-related. CoreService != WCF.
- [customurls](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customurls): rename to custom-url?
- [external-integrations](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-integrations): is the word "external" required? Doesn't [integrations](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrations) already implies it is with something else than Tridion?
- [custom-events](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-events): rename to [event-system](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-system)?

Opinions? Leave them below as an answer.

In addition: would we be allowed to copy the definitions for a common tag (for instance [xml](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml)) from StackOverflow?

Comment: I kind of like short tags, so perhaps just module-config instead of module-configuration

Comment: It would be interesting to know what Anna Lear and Robert Cartaino have observed with regards to this on other SE sites.

Comment: This question makes me wish my company’s taxonomist/library scientist wasn’t on vacation this week.

Comment: Does it make me "old-skool" if I prefer events-system to event-system, or just a pedant? I know "event system" seems to be more popular usage these days, but still. Start as we mean to go on?

Comment: I think the question makes you Dominic Cronin! :-P Care to debate schema vs. schemas and criteria vs. criterion vs. criterias.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessarily bad to have ‘generic’ tags in some cases.

Based on what I have seen with editors of my company’s websites, I think having more generic terms could reduce the confusion, hesitation and doubt people may have when deciding which tags to apply to their questions. For instance, tagging a question about CME Configuration with both the [cme](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme) and [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) tags may actually be more intuitive to a poster then tagging the question [cme-configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme-configuration).

Generic terms would seem to make it easier for community members to monitor areas of interest to them. If I am interested in questions about configuration I would rather be able to follow just [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) then [cme-configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme-configuration), [exp-configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exp-configuration), [powertools-configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powertools-configuration) etc. Likewise if someone is interested in questions about the cme I would think they would rather be able to follow [cme](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme) then having to follow [cme-configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme-configuration), [cme-operations](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme-operations),[cme-extensions](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cme-extensions)

With that said, I agree with all your proposed changes except for:

- [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) which I think should be kept for the reasons outlined above
- [wcf](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcf) which I think should be kept as [wcf](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcf) and `core services` are two different things.

Comment: for the `[module]-configuration` tags I do propose `[module]-config` too like Chris suggested, but I guess it also makes sense to add a generic configuration, based on your explananation

Comment: If I could I'd upvote you again. Great suggestions Glenn, and good catch on [tag:configuration] being something that some people may want to track

Answer (score 3):

`anguilla` -> delete (we have `gui-extensions` already which covers the same and is clearer)

`wcf` -> delete? doesn't `core-service` cover this?

`extensions` or `extension-model` -> both are too broad for my taste. There are so many types of extensions nowadays, both in CM and CD. I'd rather see tags like `gui-extensions`, `event-system`, `custom-resolver`, `custom-storage`, etc.

Comment: OK on Anguilla. Not OK on WCF/Core-Service. For most Tridion people, Core Service is the reason why we learned WCF, but if you're an actual WCF guru, Core Service is just a service... Things like transactionality are provided by WCF, but can be used in CS. OK on the rest.

Comment: Agreed. My reasoning was that wcf questions are not really tridion related at all, but that would mean we would have to ban those questions altogether, which would be a tad exaggerated..

Answer (score 2):

I would keep `embedded-schema`, although it should be renamed or a synonym be created named `embeddable-schema` (that's the official name). It can be related to the `schema` tag. It could give some more detail on Schema related questions, on the other hand, it will probably also be clear enough to tag those questions with just Schema indeed.

`configuration` -> undecided, based on Glenn's explanation I would agree to keep it

`deployment`-> delete

`long-running` -> delete

`extension-model` -> replace with `extensions`

`communicator` -> replace with cme (optionally would be to make it a synonym of CME)

`wcf` -> rename to core-service (although WCF as a tag itself might be appropriate at some point, but should not create confusion with core-service)

Answer (score 2):

how about using some of the terms that come from Tridion reference, for example, deployer or presentation-server

things that people relate to when dealing with Tridion first hand

Answer (score 0):

Except embedded-schema, for remaining tags I will go with you.

- embedded-schema: Better it should be made as a `synonyms` for `Schema`

Comment: I'd rather keep embedded-schema as is than make it a synonym for schema. Synonyms imply they're the same. For example, we'd probably want template-building-blocks to be distinct from component-templates (even if we generalize both under "template" or "templating").

Comment: If we go down that route, then we will end up with another tag for "parameter-schema" or "bundle-type-schema", etc. Might become too specific, and I don't really think it needs to. This is a community effort though, so let's do it by what we _all_ think is right.

Comment: Aye, I am fine with fewer tags and just using `schema` and just `template`. I feel "synonym" shouldn't be mistaken for "related to." In other words, an embedded-schema is a schema, but not all schemas are embedded. They're really not *synonyms*. :-)