# Should deployment be a synonym for content-delivery?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In looking at the Tag Synonyms (https://tridion.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) suggested by Bart, one of the suggestions that really stood out to me as maybe not being a good idea is the one for making [deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) a synonym for [content-delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery).

To me it looks like two of the questions ([Developing Page/Component Template Designs through Visual Studio](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13/developing-page-component-template-designs-through-visual-studio) and [How can Content Porter be automated to move commonly changed items between environments?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/290/how-can-content-porter-be-automated-to-move-commonly-changed-items-between-envir)) are actually about deploying (or moving) items to/between Tridion instances and not really about content-delivery in any way.

It looks like another two questions ([Aspx page rendering SmartTarget <tcdl> tags](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/158/aspx-page-rendering-smarttarget-tcdl-tags) and [Publishing issue for a single page](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/256/publishing-issue-for-a-single-page)) are really about publishing and the deployer and not specifically about content-delivery.

It looks like really the only question that might be considered to be about content-delivery is [Implementing Multiple deployers/Broker databases vs. replication](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/348/implementing-multiple-deployers-broker-databases-vs-replication) even though it really spans publishing, the deployer and content-delivery.

So, the questions I have are:

- Does this Synonym really make sense?
- Is a better approach in this case to ensure there is a tag wiki for [deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) explaining when to use that tag along with additional instructions in the tag wiki’s for [content-delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery) and [publishing](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing)?
- Although most of us probably consider the deployer services/storage as part of ‘publishing’ would it reduce some confusion if we had a [deployer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployer) tag in addition to the [publishing](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best answer here is to retag the two questions which are about the software release process with an appropriate tag and then retag the rest of the questions currently marked with [deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) as [content-delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery) and when/if I have enough rep to vote on Bart’s synonym suggestion to do so.

We also should probably put a ‘when to use this tag’ section in [content-delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery)’s tag wiki.

The question then becomes, what is the right tag for the questions about the software release process?

I worry the suggested tags [releases](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/releases) [software-release](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-release) and [software-builds](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-builds) all have a potential issue that someone think questions with those tags are talking about SDL releases (but I might just be overthinking this.)

This leaves the suggestions from Rob and Alvin of [release-process](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-process), [code-deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-deployment) or [development-practices](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-practices) I tend to lean towards the latter as it is a little broader in scope and could be used to cover other areas of the SDLC.

**EDIT:** I retagged the two questions about the release process with [release-process](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-process), approved and merged the suggested synonym mapping [deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) to [content-delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery)

Comment: I prefer [tag:release-process] as [tag:development-practices] seems a little broad to me.

Answer (score 4):

I agree (as the asker as one of the questions tagged as such) that [deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) is not necessarily talking about the [deployer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployer).

Moving items between environments is a complex issue that definitely should be represented by a tag here. Perhaps [releases](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/releases) or [release-process](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-process) would be better to avoid confusion with the Content Delivery [deployer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployer)?

Answer (score 3):

*Updated to match actual question--oops.*

For moving changes between Dev Test Acceptance or Production (DTAP) environments, maybe we could use something about code or software builds.

- [code-deployment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-deployment)
- [software-release](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-release)
- [software-builds](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-builds)
- [development-practices](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-practices)?

We can also consider deleting `deployment` as a tag and see if `deployer` or specific customizations would be better tags?

**Nuno and Bart actually suggest `deployment` is a bit generic in our [Meta discussion on tags](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/46).** Removing that tag could be an option to not confuse it with deployer (like I did in my first answer), which *is* a part of `content-delivery` and includes Custom Protocol, Resolver, Renderer, Sender, Module and/or Processor, and Storage.

[SDL Live Content has another nice overview](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_035EA0408E7848AD99A98F69DFECF33A) that points these out. These specific tags could help avoid confusion with the generic idea of "deployment" of content or code changes.

Comment: What would you tag the 2 questions that were actually talking about deploying code/templates/what have you between environments?

Comment: Oh, duh, I missed the context. .NET devs might call it "publishing." :-( Code-deployment? Porting? Development-practices? It's almost like the answer would have the tag if that makes sense.

Comment: updated answer to match the *real* question :0)

Answer (score 1):

`Deployment` and `Content Delivery` are definitely not synonyms. `Content Delivery` generally means "delivering content to the web visitor". `Deployment` in Tridion terms usually means content deployment, which is what the `Deployer` does. Some people on the team will also use it to mean web application deployment. Whatever - there's a bunch of assets that need to be deployed to a delivery server to allow the visitor to experience the content.

Other than that specific sense of Content Delivery, we also use the term to refer to the entire Content Delivery environment or environments, and everything that happens there. So anything that isn't Content Management is Content Delivery.

(In a Tridion context, Transport almost always means "Transport of deployment assets from the Content Management system to the Content Delivery system". In this sense, it can either be part of CM, or CD, both or none.)

Comment: So Dominic, do you think we should remove the synonym pointing Deployment to Content Delivery? How would we get over the issue of people taking non-deployment questions and 'Deployment? (Constant vigilance I guess.) Our should we create a 'content-deployment' tag and map 'deployment' to it.

Comment: As I said - they are not synonyms. Deployment is often seen as /part/ of Content Delivery, but the meanings are distinct. Synonyms are more useful when the_same_thing is referred to by two or more terms. E.g. "Tridion Content Explorer" a.k.a. "The GUI". (hmm - maybe that's not a perfect example)